# Find all locked users in AD using c#

Tags: c#, active-directory

The code listed below works fine for me however i would like a list of all users that are locked as opposed to specifying a particular user, can some one help me broaden the scope of this code please

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Domain ))
{
     using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity( context,
                                                     IdentityType.SamAccountName,
                                                     name ))
     {
          if (user.IsAccountLockedOut())
          {
              ... your code here...
          }
     }
}
```

The code listed above works fine for me however i would like a list of all users that are locked as opposed to specifying a particular user.

Here is what ended up working - Thanks to all contributors.
when a user is locked they dont go to "not locked" until they log in (when refferencing the lockedout clause in a ldap search); so... Using the locked out qry Gives you a broad list of locked out users which you can then narrow down with the isaccountlockedout() method.  Regards!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Lockout : IDisposable
    {
        DirectoryContext context;
        DirectoryEntry root;


        public Lockout()
        {
            string domainName = "domain.com";
            this.context = new DirectoryContext(
              DirectoryContextType.Domain,
              domainName
              );

            //get our current domain policy
            Domain domain = Domain.GetDomain(this.context);

            this.root = domain.GetDirectoryEntry();

        }

        public void FindLockedAccounts()
        {

            string qry = " (&(&(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(lockoutTime:1.2.840.113556.1.4.804:=4294967295)(!UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536)))) ";
            DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(
              this.root,
              qry
              );

            using (SearchResultCollection src = ds.FindAll())
            {
                foreach (SearchResult sr in src)
                {


                    using (var context = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Domain ))
                        {
    string name = sr.Properties["SamAccountName"][0].ToString();
     using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity( context,
                                                     IdentityType.SamAccountName,
                                                     name ))
                                 {  
          if (user.IsAccountLockedOut())
                                                 {
              Console.WriteLine("{0} is locked out", sr.Properties["name"][0]);

                                                 } 
                                 }
                        }



                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (this.root != null)
            {
                this.root.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Misread question. Updated answer

Try it now

Why not just:

```
        var lockedUsers = new List<UserPrincipal>();
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "Domain Users");
            foreach (var userPrincipal in grp.GetMembers(false))
            {
                var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName);                        
                if (user != null)
                {
                    if (user.IsAccountLockedOut())
                    {
                        lockedUsers.Add(user);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
//Deal with list here
```

[Check here if you'd like to see more](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ecb16a63-6619-4c68-a77c-8bb2682fc1be/get-list-of-active-directory-users-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: This is still referencing "name" which is requesting a name value be supplied

Comment: Thanks! The only thing is "isaccountlockedout()" is creating an error , "accountmanagement.principal does not contain a definition..."  upon removing it and checking the available options in intellisense there isnt a similar command available

Comment: Dang, I almost had it. Try the new edit. It's not the most efficient, but it (should) works.

Comment: :D It was able to build this time around; I just got a object refference not set to an instance of an object error.  line 29 ==  if (user.IsAccountLockedOut())     .

Comment: I added a catch for if the user is not null. You can also put the IsAccountLockedOut() statement into a try/catch

Comment: i was able to figure it out with a mixture of what i had, what you provided, and Brian's answer.
Thanks! Updated code listed above in case you want to check it out

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `lockoutTime` attribute, but, it's not necessarily trivial. The attribute has the time the user was locked out at. So, if your domain has a single lockout policy, you can do a search for everyone whose `lockoutTime` value is greater than or equal to (UTC Now - Lockout Duration).

If you have multiple lockout policies via fine grained password policies, then this is not so easy since you need to calculate it on a per user basis.

If your domain has a permanent lockout (e.g. you must request an account unlock), you can search on greater than zero.